# How to display the JQPLOT graph rather a long text

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, jqplot

I have a method in controller class which returns JSON data:

```
public ActionResult ChartDataJSON()
{
    Chart chart = new Chart();
    DataSet ds = dbLayer.GetChartData();
    DataTable dtChartData = ds.Tables[0];
    List<jqplotModel> chartData = new List<jqplotModel>();

    if (dtChartData .Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dtChartData .Rows)
        {
            chartData.Add(new jqplotModel{ Date = DateTime.Parse(@row["Date"].ToString()), Demand= Convert.ToDouble(@row["Demand"].ToString()), Supply= Convert.ToDouble(@row["Supply"].ToString()) });
        }
    }
    return Json(chartData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Does anybody know how I can use it in my script. I tried with these lines but it is not showing the chart

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var types = ['Demand', 'Supply'];               

        var rawData =  function (url, plot, options) {
            var ret = null;
            $.ajax({
                // have to use synchronous here, else the function
                // will return before the data is fetched
                async: false,
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    ret = data;
                }
            });
            return ret;
        };

        // The url for our json data
        var jsonurl = "/ChartController/ChartDataJSON";
        var plotData = []

        for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
            //Parse the date.
            var date = new Date(+rawData[i].Date.match(/\d+/));

            plotData[i] = [date, rawData[i].Demand];
        }

        var plotData2 = []

        for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
            //Parse the date.
            var date = new Date(+rawData[i].Date.match(/\d+/));

            plotData2[i] = [date, rawData[i].Supply];
        }

        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [plotData, plotData2], {
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
            title: 'Demand Supply',
            dataRenderer: rawData,
            dataRendererOptions: {
                unusedOptionalUrl: jsonurl
            },
            series: [
                    {},
                    { yaxis: 'y2axis' }
            ],
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    tickOptions: { formatString: '%#I %p' },
                    label: "Date",
                    tickInterval: '4 hour'
                },
                yaxis: {
                    label: "Demand",
                    labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer

                },
                y2axis: {
                    label: "Supply",
                    labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
                }
            },
            highlighter: {
                show: true,
                sizeAdjust: 1
            },
            cursor: {
                show: false
            },
            legend: {
                show: true,
                labels: types,
                location: 'ne'
            }
        });

        $(window).bind('resize', function (event, ui) {
            if (plot1) {
                plot1.replot();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I run this I don't see the chart, and the page displays a long text like this:

> [{"Demand":4422.45,"Supply":17660,"Date":"/Date(1236504600000)/","DateString":"3 PM"},{"Demand":5019.27,"Supply":20699,"Date":"/Date(1236508200000)/","DateString":"4 PM"},{"Demand":5030.35,"Supply":19917,"Date":"/Date(1236511800000)/","DateString":"5 PM"},{"Demand":5172.35,"Supply":23597,"Date":"/Date(1236515400000)/","DateString":"6 PM"},{"Demand":5656.51,"Supply":21572,"Date":"/Date(1236519000000)/","DateString":"7 PM"},{"Demand":4622.88,"Supply":7794,"Date":"/Date(1236522600000)/","DateString":"8 PM"},{"Demand":3116.21,"Supply":3427,"Date":"/Date(1236526200000)/","DateString":"9 PM"},{"Demand":1588.83,"Supply":1883,"Date":"/Date(1236529800000)/","DateString":"10 PM"},{"Demand":1394.15,"Supply":1403,"Date":"/Date(1236533400000)/","DateString":"11 PM"},{"Demand":1321.76,"Supply":3755,"Date":"/Date(1236537000000)/","DateString":"12 AM"},{"Demand":1130.98,"Supply":3474,"Date":"/Date(1236540600000)/","DateString":"1 AM"},{"Demand":1277.1,"Supply":1072,"Date":"/Date(1236544200000)/","DateString":"2 AM"},{"Demand":1214.68,"Supply":1025,"Date":"/Date(1236547800000)/","DateString":"3 AM"},{"Demand":2117.91,"Supply":1198,"Date":"/Date(1236551400000)/","DateString":"4 AM"},{"Demand":1658.97,"Supply":1485,"Date":"/Date(1236555000000)/","DateString":"5 AM"},{"Demand":1997.36,"Supply":3126,"Date":"/Date(1236558600000)/","DateString":"6 AM"},{"Demand":2147.37,"Supply":4785,"Date":"/Date(1236562200000)/","DateString":"7 AM"},{"Demand":2114.13,"Supply":5268,"Date":"/Date(1236565800000)/","DateString":"8 AM"},{"Demand":2389.84,"Supply":5264,"Date":"/Date(1236569400000)/","DateString":"9 AM"},{"Demand":2240.77,"Supply":5526,"Date":"/Date(1236573000000)/","DateString":"10 AM"},{"Demand":1802.43,"Supply":4530,"Date":"/Date(1236576600000)/","DateString":"11 AM"},{"Demand":1929.71,"Supply":6618,"Date":"/Date(1236580200000)/","DateString":"12 PM"},{"Demand":545.65,"Supply":2767,"Date":"/Date(1236583800000)/","DateString":"1 PM"},{"Demand":0,"Supply":1,"Date":"/Date(1236587400000)/","DateString":"2 PM"}]

Can anybody help me figure out the problem and where and what I am doing wrong?

Edit: 
Please note that the data would be dynamic and it would be coming from the database and through coding in controller class it will be returning the JSON script to the view. Please suggest how to pass/use the JSON object (from ChartDataJSON() method) in jqPlot.

Comment: I don't know the answer but have you seen DotNet Highcharts for MVC? http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so here is my answer.

My controller is as follows:

```
public class jqPlotController : Controller
{    
    public ActionResult ChartDataJSON()
    {
        var chartData = new List<jqplotModel>();

        var point1 = new jqplotModel { Date = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mmtt"), Demand = Convert.ToDouble(1), Supply = Convert.ToDouble(3) };
        var point2 = new jqplotModel { Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mmtt"), Demand = Convert.ToDouble(2), Supply = Convert.ToDouble(4) };
        var point3 = new jqplotModel { Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(31).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mmtt"), Demand = Convert.ToDouble(6), Supply = Convert.ToDouble(6) };
        var point4 = new jqplotModel { Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(106).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:mmtt"), Demand = Convert.ToDouble(4), Supply = Convert.ToDouble(2) };
        chartData.Add(point1);
        chartData.Add(point2);
        chartData.Add(point3);
        chartData.Add(point4);

        return Json(chartData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    //
    // GET: /jqPlot/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And the model:

```
public class jqplotModel
{
 public string Date { get; set; }
 public double Demand { get; set; }
 public double Supply { get; set; }
}
```

I've hard coded a (very!) simple dataset in the ChartDataJSON method. It will be pretty trivial for you to refactor your code to output data in a similar format.

As I'm new to jqPlot it took me a while to figure out how to pass a DateTime object to this javascript library. Every time I tried jqPlot gave me pretty cryptic time related error message. The solution I found was to format it as a date time which jqPlot understands e.g. '2008-09-30 4:00PM' (see example [here](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/date-axes.php)) - I'm sure this is going to be useful for others confused about jqPlot's handling of dates!

The view looks as follows:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("Scripts/jqPlot/jquery.jqplot.js")"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("Scripts/jqPlot/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js")"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("Scripts/jqPlot/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js")"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("Scripts/jqPlot/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js")"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("Scripts/jqPlot/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js")"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("Scripts/jqPlot/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js")"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("Scripts/jqPlot/plugins/jqplot.highlighter.min.js")"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // The url for our json data
        var url = '@Url.Action("ChartDataJSON", "jqPlot")';

        var ret = null;
        $.ajax({
            // have to use synchronous here, else the function 
            // will return before the data is fetched
            async: false,
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                ret = data;
            }
        });

        var demands = [];
        var supplys = [];

        for (i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
            // Save the data to the relevant array. Note how date at the zeroth position (i.e. x-axis) is common for both demand and supply arrays.
            demands.push([ret[i].Date, ret[i].Demand]);
            supplys.push([ret[i].Date, ret[i].Supply]);
        }

        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [demands, supplys], {
            title: "Demand Supply",
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: '%d/%m/%Y'
                    },

                    label: 'Date'
                },
                yaxis: {
                    label: 'Demand'
                },
                y2axis: {
                    label: 'Supply'
                }
            },
            series: [
                { yaxis: 'yaxis', label: 'demands' },
                { yaxis: 'y2axis', label: 'supplys' }
            ],
            highlighter: {
                show: true,
                sizeAdjust: 1
            },
            cursor: {
                show: false
            }
        });
    });
</script>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "jQPlot Demo";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<div id="chart1" style="height: 400px; width: 600px;"></div>
```

Note that in my solution I don't use the datarender option. Instead I retrieve the data using the jquery ajax call and then I create two separate arrays for the Demand and Supply data. Each of these arrays have the date in the x-axis, and then their respective value in the y-axis (hence the date is obviously common to both arrays).

Once I had this data I then plotted it via jqPlot, which results in the following graph:

[image: Graph produced when code is run]

Work still needs to be done to refine the ticks on the axis and the labelling, but hopefully this is the kind graph you want. If not, then it certainly has been a good learning task for me and I hope others will find this useful.

Comment: Hello Fresh, I ran your code in my application and it still gives me the text like this on the web page [{"Date":"2013-10-21 12:00AM","Demand":1,"Supply":3},{"Date":"2013-10-31 12:00AM","Demand":2,"Supply":4},{"Date":"2013-11-21 12:00AM","Demand":6,"Supply":6},{"Date":"2014-02-04 12:00AM","Demand":4,"Supply":2}]

I copied your code as it is with no changes but still can't see the graph. Do you have any idea why it is not showing the graph. Thank you for trying, appreciate it!

Comment: Check in the browser debug console for errors. Double check that the necessary jquery and jqPlot libraries (i.e. the js files) are being referenced properly.

Comment: I checked all the js files and they are fine. In fact with hard code data it is working fine but when i change the code to get data from json the chart is not rendered :(

Comment: So have you checked the browser debug console? Any errors? Have you put a breakpoint in your controller in GetChartJson? Also check that you Url.Action i.e. '@Url.Action("ChartDataJSON", "jqPlot")' is correct for your controller.

Comment: No errors but it still does not show the chart. I wrote an alert line in script function but the alert too is not shown. Can't find out what and how to resolve this. totally disturbed.

Comment: It looks like a browser side issue. Check that you haven't got javascript turned off in the browser. Also are you debugging the javascript? Additionally put a breakpoint in the c# controller to double-check that the method is being called.

Comment: I wish i can attach a sample application. I tried this in 3 different browser and the result is same. While debugging i can see the json data in controller class and further To debug i wrote this line in js script alert(ret); to check what data is coming but when i run this i do not see the alert as well as chart.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39662/discussion-between-fresh-and-user1254053)

Comment: This does not show the graph in IE 8 due to javascript error.

Comment: This line needs to be added: <!--[if IE]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jqPlot/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->

Comment: Hi @BenSmith thanks for the example I am not getting the date value in the chart as I am passing the direct value from the database

Answer (score 1):

I think this should solve your problem: [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ZChhN/1/)

- i have declared `rawData` as a variable which would contain the ajaxreply json object. then i have used that variable below to plot the graph.
- in your code i observed that you are already supplying data to the graph and you also have dataRenderer set inside it. that is not correct. [DataRenderer examples](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/data-renderers.php)

  ```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  ```

  var rawData = [{"Demand":4422.45,"Supply":17660,"Date":"/Date(1236504600000)/","DateString":"3 PM"},{"Demand":5019.27,"Supply":20699,"Date":"/Date(1236508200000)/","DateString":"4 PM"},{"Demand":5030.35,"Supply":19917,"Date":"/Date(1236511800000)/","DateString":"5 PM"},{"Demand":5172.35,"Supply":23597,"Date":"/Date(1236515400000)/","DateString":"6 PM"},{"Demand":5656.51,"Supply":21572,"Date":"/Date(1236519000000)/","DateString":"7 PM"},{"Demand":4622.88,"Supply":7794,"Date":"/Date(1236522600000)/","DateString":"8 PM"},{"Demand":3116.21,"Supply":3427,"Date":"/Date(1236526200000)/","DateString":"9 PM"},{"Demand":1588.83,"Supply":1883,"Date":"/Date(1236529800000)/","DateString":"10 PM"},{"Demand":1394.15,"Supply":1403,"Date":"/Date(1236533400000)/","DateString":"11 PM"},{"Demand":1321.76,"Supply":3755,"Date":"/Date(1236537000000)/","DateString":"12 AM"},{"Demand":1130.98,"Supply":3474,"Date":"/Date(1236540600000)/","DateString":"1 AM"},{"Demand":1277.1,"Supply":1072,"Date":"/Date(1236544200000)/","DateString":"2 AM"},{"Demand":1214.68,"Supply":1025,"Date":"/Date(1236547800000)/","DateString":"3 AM"},{"Demand":2117.91,"Supply":1198,"Date":"/Date(1236551400000)/","DateString":"4 AM"},{"Demand":1658.97,"Supply":1485,"Date":"/Date(1236555000000)/","DateString":"5 AM"},{"Demand":1997.36,"Supply":3126,"Date":"/Date(1236558600000)/","DateString":"6 AM"},{"Demand":2147.37,"Supply":4785,"Date":"/Date(1236562200000)/","DateString":"7 AM"},{"Demand":2114.13,"Supply":5268,"Date":"/Date(1236565800000)/","DateString":"8 AM"},{"Demand":2389.84,"Supply":5264,"Date":"/Date(1236569400000)/","DateString":"9 AM"},{"Demand":2240.77,"Supply":5526,"Date":"/Date(1236573000000)/","DateString":"10 AM"},{"Demand":1802.43,"Supply":4530,"Date":"/Date(1236576600000)/","DateString":"11 AM"},{"Demand":1929.71,"Supply":6618,"Date":"/Date(1236580200000)/","DateString":"12 PM"},{"Demand":545.65,"Supply":2767,"Date":"/Date(1236583800000)/","DateString":"1 PM"},{"Demand":0,"Supply":1,"Date":"/Date(1236587400000)/","DateString":"2 PM"}];

  ```
      var types = ['Demand', 'Supply'];               

      var plotData = []

      for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
          //Parse the date.
          var date = new Date(+rawData[i].Date.match(/\d+/));

          plotData[i] = [date, rawData[i].Demand];
      }

      var plotData2 = []

      for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
          //Parse the date.
          var date = new Date(+rawData[i].Date.match(/\d+/));

          plotData2[i] = [date, rawData[i].Supply];
      }

      var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [plotData, plotData2], {
          height: 300,
          width: 300,
          title: 'Demand Supply',
          //dataRenderer: rawData,
          //dataRendererOptions: {
          //    unusedOptionalUrl: jsonurl
          //},
          series: [
                  {},
                  { yaxis: 'y2axis' }
          ],
          axes: {
              xaxis: {
                  renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                  tickOptions: { formatString: '%#I %p' },
                  label: "Date"
                  //,tickInterval: '4 Hr'
              },
              yaxis: {
                  label: "Demand"
                  //,labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer

              },
              y2axis: {
                  label: "Supply"
                  //,labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
              }
          },
          highlighter: {
              show: true,
              sizeAdjust: 1
          },
          cursor: {
              show: false
          },
          legend: {
              show: true,
              labels: types,
              location: 'ne'
          }
      });

      $(window).bind('resize', function (event, ui) {
          if (plot1) {
              plot1.replot();
          }
      });

  });
  ```

Comment: Thank you Gyandeep but this is not what I want. My data would be dynamic and would be coming from the database. I already know it works if i hard code the data as variable..anybody working with jqplot knows it.  I want to know how can i pass the json string from controller class to the view. Hope you know the mvc concepts.

Answer (score 0):

As [@user1254053](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1254053/user1254053) I also had trouble implementing [@Fresh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203371/fresh)'s solution.
I was trying to write the js code in my ChartDataJSON view, I mean in the view from the ChartDataJSON() method and I just got plain text objects printed out when running my view.

Then I tried to write my view code in another view, the index view for example or any other view that just has a `return(View)` statement and worked out.

I hope this may help other people and I wish I'm not too late.

Comment: What exactly did you have trouble implementing? I maybe able to help.

Comment: I think I already explained in my answer. I tried one way and failed and then tried out the other way and succeeded.
And I thought that was what @user1254053 was having trouble with, that's why I posted this answer.