# JQPlot, JSON and 'No data specified' Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asmx, jqplot

I am trying to use JQPlot within a VB.NET application under .NET 3.5.  On a button click, using jquery, I am trying to populate the JQPlot Chart with JSON derived data using a ASP.NET Webservices Source file (which is part of the solution).

The JSON data is sent by the web service but when it is presented to JQPlot I get the javascript error 'No Data Specified' which is generated by JQPlot code.

My code listing is as follows:

Code to listen for the button to be clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#<%=btnASMX1.ClientID%>').click(function () {
  getElectricDataJSON();
 return false;
 });
});
```

Javascript code outside the 'document.ready' function:

```
function ajaxDataRenderer() {
 var ret = null;
 $.ajax({
  // have to use synchronous here, else the function 
  // will return before the data is fetched
  async: false,
  //url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  url: "AccountsService.asmx/GetJSONData",
  data: "{AccountID: " + $('#<%= hiddenAccountID.ClientID%>').val() + " }",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (response) {
   var ret = response.d;
   // The following two lines just display the JSON data for testing purposes
   $('#<%=outputASMX.ClientID%>').empty();
   $('#<%=outputASMX.ClientID%>').html("<div>" + ret + "</div>");
   return ret;
  },
  error: function (request) {
   $('#<%=outputASMX.ClientID%>').html("<div style='color:red;'>WEBSERVICE UNREACHABLE</div>");
  }
 });
 return ret;
};

var jsonurl = "./jsondata.txt";

function getElectricDataJSON() {
 var ret = ajaxDataRenderer();
 var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart2', jsonurl, {
 title: "AJAX JSON Data Renderer",
 dataRenderer: ret, //$.jqplot.ciParser
 dataRendererOptions: {
  unusedOptionalUrl: jsonurl
 }
});
}
```

The JSON data format is as follows:

```
[ { "todate": "2013-09-23T00:00:00", "Bill": 7095.65 }, { "todate": "2013-08-22T00:00:00", "Bill": 1137.96 }, { "todate": "2013-07-24T00:00:00", "Bill": 220429.41 }, ... ]
```

Any help or advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Did my answer help? I apologise if the opening sentence in the answer is rather blunt!

Comment: @Fresh
It appeared that I needed to convert the data that was sent by the web service from being a string object to a JSON array.  After `var ret = ajaxDataRenderer();` in the getElectricDataJSON() function, I inserted `var ret = JSON.parse(ret);` and then

  // Now push required data into a JSON array object
  var sampleData = [], item;
  $.each(ret, function (key, value) {
  sampleData.push([value.todate, parseFloat(value.Bill.replace(/,/g, ""))]);
  });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Fresh for their quick response.  Here is the complete solution to my problem:

---

Code to listen for the button to be clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#<%=btnASMX1.ClientID%>').click(function () {
  getElectricDataJSON();
 return false;
 });
});
```

---

JS function to get the data from a web service:

```
function ajaxDataRenderer() {
 var ret = null;
 $.ajax({
  // have to use synchronous here, else the function 
  // will return before the data is fetched
  async: false,
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  url: "AccountsService.asmx/GetJSONData",
  data: "{AccountID: " + $('#<%= hiddenAccountID.ClientID%>').val() + " }",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (response) {
    ret = response.d; // return response string object
  },
  error: function (request) {
   $('#<%=outputASMX.ClientID%>').html("<div style='color:red;'>WEBSERVICE    UNREACHABLE</div>");
  }
 });
 return ret;
};
```

---

Data structure outputted by the web service is:

```
[ { "todate": "2013-09-23T00:00:00", "Bill": 7,095.65 }, { "todate": "2013-08-22T00:00:00", "Bill": 1,137.96 }, { "todate": "2013-07-24T00:00:00", "Bill": 220,429.41 }, ... ]
```

---

Data structure that is expected by JQPlot:

```
[ [ "2013-09-23T00:00:00", 7095.65 ] , [ "2013-08-22T00:00:00", 1137.96 ], [ "2013-07-24T00:00:00", 220429.41 ], ... ]
```

Note the removal of the comma's in the 'expected data' Bill field.

---

And finally, the function **getElectricDataJSON()** that is being called by **btnASMX1** where 'chart2' is the ID of the div tags where the chart will be drawn.

```
function getElectricDataJSON() {

 // Get JSON 'string' object
 var ret = ajaxDataRenderer();

 // If JSON string object is null, stop processing with friendly message
 if (ret == null) {
   $('#<%=outputASMX.ClientID%>').html("<div style='color:red;'>CHARTS ARE NOT AVAILABLE AT THIS TIME</div>");
   return false;
 }

 // Now push required data into a JSON array object
 var sampleData = [], item;
 $.each(ret, function (key, value) {
   sampleData.push([value.todate, parseFloat(value.Bill.replace(/,/g, ""))]);
 });

 var plot = $.jqplot('chart2', [sampleData], {
   title: 'AJAX JSON Data Renderer',
   dataRenderer: sampleData,
   ...      
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method signature for your datarender (i.e. ajaxDataRender) is wrong. The signature should look like this:

> function(userData, plotObject, options) {   ...   return data; }

(See the documentation [here](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/data-renderers.php))

In your example you are passing the datarenderer "ret" which is not a function with the correct datarender signature. Also the jsonurl you are passing to getElectricDataJSON() is redundant as at no point in your code is the data from "AccountsService.asmx/GetJSONData" persisted to "./jsondata.txt".

Hence you should change your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 function ajaxDataRenderer(url, plot, options) {
  var ret = null;
  $.ajax({
   // have to use synchronous here, else the function 
   // will return before the data is fetched
   async: false,
   url: url,
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (response) {
    var ret = response;
    // The following two lines just display the JSON data for testing purposes
    $('#<%=outputASMX.ClientID%>').empty();
    $('#<%=outputASMX.ClientID%>').html("<div>" + ret + "</div>");
   },
   error: function (request) {
    $('#<%=outputASMX.ClientID%>').html("<div style='color:red;'>WEBSERVICE UNREACHABLE</div>");
   }
  });
  return ret;
 };

 var url = "AccountsService.asmx/GetJSONData";

 function getElectricDataJSON() {
  var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart2', url, {
  title: "AJAX JSON Data Renderer",
  dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
 });
}
```

Comment: I am assuming that the object 'jsonurl' in the 'getElectricDataJSON' function should be changed to 'url'?  When I do this, I get the 'No Data Specified' message generated from jquery.jqplot.js.  I will investigate what sort of data is being passed by my web service as I suspect it is passing a string rather than an object that contains true JSON-friendly data.

Comment: Yes, I've updated my example so that $.jqplot is passed URL. If your ajax call is working then your success method should display the result on screen. Another approach you could take is not use the datareader, but instead pass in the json directly to jqplot. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19484445/203371)